# Getting 403 Error: Tunnel or SSL firbidden

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to publish the wso2 ESB application from wso2 developer studio. I am getting "Getting 403 Error: Tunnel or SSL firbidden".

Server is running on local system.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Trying to register the smooks config file from developer studii, but getting the same error "Transport Error:403 Error: Tunnel or SSL forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

I not sure your question is, please provider more details. Like what your wso2 ESB application? Proxy service?
But...
1. Do you try to import the public Cert of your back end **https** service to $esb_home/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the backend cert.

keytool -import -alias alias -file .pem -keystore .jks -storepass password

Also make sure you have enabled SSL tunneling correctly. You can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enabling+SSL+Tunneling+through+a+Proxy+Server) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, what I understand is that you are trying to deploy an ESB application from the WSO2 Developer Studio to your local ESB server. Developer Studio will use an admin service which is hosted in WSO2 ESB server to upload the artifacts. If you have installed a new certificate to your ESB server, this kind of error can happen. If that is the case, you need to import that certificate to Dev Studio as well.